# Text.set(string) not showing the right value in hadoop map reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a map function that sends data in the form of (the value of they keys are not important)

```
key: "somevalue"
value: "value \t comma separated values"
```

for example

```
key:"0"
value:"5\t1,2,3,4"
```

If I use this code:

```
Text debug;
for (Text val : values) {
    String[] segments = val.toString().split("\t");
    debug = new Text();
    debug.set(val.toString());
    context.write(key, debug);
}
```

I get the right output, such as

```
key value
0   8   1,2,4,5
0   2   0,4,5
```

But if I try this code, the output gets weird:

```
Text debug;
for (Text val : values) {
    String[] segments = val.toString().split("\t");
    debug = new Text();
    if(val.toString().split("\t").length > 1) {
        try{
            debug.set(val.toString().split("\t")[1]);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            debug.set("Exception")
        }
    }
    context.write(key, debug);
}
```

The expected output would be:

```
key  second part of value (after \t) 
1    2,3,4,5,6
1    4,5,6,6,7
```

However the output I get is this:

```
key Tab (tab character after key)
1TAB
1TAB
...
2TAB
```

If I replace the `try...catch` with `if...else`:

```
Text debug;
for (Text val : values) {
    String[] segments = val.toString().split("\t");
    debug = new Text();
    if(val.toString().split("\t").length > 1) {
        debug.set(val.toString().split("\t")[1]);
    } else {
        debug.set("only one");
    }
    context.write(key, debug);
}
```

This gives the result

```
0   only one
...
100 only one
```

What's going on? I checked on Java and it seems that if I call `"1\t2".split("\t")` it will give me `["1", "2"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, I was using it as both a combiner and a reducer. Just needed to use it only as reducer.